# autofs asks password for passwordless samba share on Centos 7

Tags: centos, systemd, samba, autofs

I have a samba share that does not require password. Here are non-default lines in my `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
map to guest = Bad User

[distr-ro]
        path = /home/distr
        public = yes
        writable = no
```

On RHEL6 I added this line to `/etc/auto.master` and it worked:

```
/cifs   /etc/auto.smb --timeout=60
```

But on Centos 7 attempt to access the share hangs and I see a broadcast message

```
[root@wc8 etc]# ls /cifs/okdistr/distr-ro

Broadcast message from root@wc8 (Wed 2016-03-02 03:51:45 EST):

Password entry required for 'Password for root@//okdistr/distr-ro:' (PID 10006).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!
```

Comment: You need a better auto.smb script. Unfortunately, all those I found fail in various situations. I'm working on writing my own now...

Comment: @mivk `guest` mount option helps. See below.

Comment: `guest` only "helps" if the server accepts listing shares without authentication of course. Which by default, most servers don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same annoyance. Eventually, I ended up switching the automounting to systemd.

You have to create a file in /etc/systemd/system for the mount. Naming conventions require that to be named after the mount point with the path separator replaced by dashes. Since you have a dash in the name already, you'd have to figure out how to escape that.

In my case I added /etc/systemd/system/smb-Tomato.mount.

```
[Unit]
  Description=cifs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]
  What=//<IP of server>/<path on server>
  Where=/smb/Tomato
  Options=guest,uid=<my UID on client>,gid=<my GID on client>,rw
  Type=cifs
[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I had to enable and start this mount:

```
sudo systemctl enable smb-Tomato.mount
sudo systemctl start smb-Tomato.mount
```

Since I wanted automount I also created a file /etc/systemd/system/smb-Tomato.automount containing:

```
[Unit]
  Description=cifs automount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Automount]
  Where=/smb/Tomato
  TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and simiarly enable and start this

```
sudo systemctl enable smb-Tomato.automount
sudo systemctl start smb-Tomato.automount
```

So far I'm satisfied: the annoying broadcast message has disappeared.

After doing this I figured that just using the 'guest' mount option might have done the trick, but since I already have what I was after I did not revert to try this out.

Comment: Your last sentence was helpful: `/cifs   /etc/auto.smb --timeout=60 guest`